# serverless framework with aws import function returns 404

Tags: serverless, aws-serverless

I have two serverless app which are sharing the same custom authorizer. Suddenly the import function in the second serverless.yml file stopped working.

The app is based on https://github.com/medwig/serverless-shared-authorizer

`gateway.serverless`

```
service: authorizer-stack

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: ap-south-1
  profile: xxx-dev

functions:
  authorizer:
    handler: handler.auth

  test:
    handler: handler.privateEndpoint
    events:
      - http:
          path: /api/test
          method: get
          authorizer:
            type: CUSTOM
            authorizerId:
              Ref: Authorizer

  test2:
    handler: handler.publicEndpoint
    events:
      - http:
          path: /api/test/public
          method: get

resources:
  Resources:
    AuthorizerPermission:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      Properties:
        FunctionName:
          Fn::GetAtt: AuthorizerLambdaFunction.Arn
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Principal:
          Fn::Join: ["",["apigateway.", { Ref: "AWS::URLSuffix"}]]
    Authorizer:
      DependsOn:
        - ApiGatewayRestApi
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
      Properties:
        Name: ${self:provider.stage}-Authorizer
        RestApiId: { "Ref" : "ApiGatewayRestApi" }
        Type: TOKEN
        IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
        AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 300
        AuthorizerUri:
          Fn::Join:
            - ''
            -
              - 'arn:aws:apigateway:'
              - Ref: "AWS::Region"
              - ':lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/'
              - Fn::GetAtt: "AuthorizerLambdaFunction.Arn"
              - "/invocations"

  Outputs:
    AuthorizerId:
      Value:
        Ref: Authorizer
      Export:
        Name: authorizerId
    apiGatewayRestApiId:
      Value:
        Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
      Export:
        Name: restApiId
    apiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId:
      Value:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - ApiGatewayRestApi
          - RootResourceId
      Export:
        Name: rootResourceId
```

`products serverless`

```
service: products-list

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: ap-south-1
  profile: xxx-dev
  apiGateway:
    restApiId:
      Fn::ImportValue: authorizer-stack-dev-restApiId
    restApiRootResourceId:
      Fn::ImportValue: authorizer-stack-dev-rootResourceId


functions:
  get-products:
    handler: handler.getProducts
    events:
      - http:
          path: /api/products
          method: get
          authorizer:
            type: CUSTOM
            authorizerId:
              Fn::ImportValue: authorizer-stack-dev-authorizerId
```

I am getting the following errors at random

```
 An error occurred: products-list-dev - No export named authorizer-stack-dev-restApiId found.
 An error occurred: products-list-dev - No export named authorizer-stack-dev-rootResourceId found.
 An error occurred: products-list-dev - No export named authorizer-stack-dev-authorizerId found.
```

What am I missing here?

serverless -v
Framework Core: 1.74.1
Plugin: 3.6.15
SDK: 2.3.1
Components: 2.31.10

Answer (score 1):

From the shared authorizers I have configured in the past it is not necessary to go to the effort you have undergone. The documentation on the Serverless Framework site has a much simpler setup to achieve a shared authoriser and I will always go with the simplest solution possible: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#share-authorizer

Comment: This works if there is a single serverless file and I want to share the authorizers inside one. But I am using a custom authorizer(Auth0) and a single API gateway which is shared across multiple serverless files

Comment: This works across services. You just use the ARN for the custom authorizer function instead of the name in the other services and the Serverless Framework will connect it up. I've used it myself many times.